# Documentation Java arrays not ending loading

Tags: bug, documentation

I have edited few times Java arrays in documentation. After few successful commits was one of edited articles deleted. Now when I try to access to arrays, I am facing non ending loading.

I am using `Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m (64-bit)` .

Comment: I am having this problem too even with version `52.0.2743.82 (64-bit)`.