# Why is the documentation page causing my browser to freeze?

Tags: bug, documentation

I don't know if I'm the only one experiencing this issue, but anytime I try to create a new topic or improve an existing topic, whatever browser I use the page just keeps on freezing and the browser stops responding, after a little while the browser starts responding again, then it goes back to it's previous non-responsive state.

Apparently, there's is a script that causes it to freeze, but it's minified so it's of no good to me because I can't read it

http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/docs-transpiled.en.js?v=0873da7e0e4a:1

Here is a screenshot in Palemoon browser (also experienced the same issue on Firefox and Chrome):

[image: Palemoon Screenshot]

I've also noticed that this happens only in the [odoo-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-8) tag; I've tried Python and Flask tags and I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Did you try looking at the Java Arrays documentation? That freezes it for some people, like [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329787/documentation-java-arrays-not-ending-loading)