# Documentation - Short Example VS Long Example

Tags: discussion, documentation

Should we keep example in the documentation relatively short or the bigger the better?

The example that raised this questioning is the following one : 
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201608021310364992256

It is very long and is also the most voted example at the moment (I believe).

While, I can see that a lot of work was put into this example and that it's very complete I feel that it is too big and it tries to cover too much. For example, let say I'm trying to find information about creating an array with generic and google refer me to this link. When I open it, all I see is a ton of stuff that is unrelated to what I'm searching for. Then I have to scroll / scan through the example until I finally reach the section on generic.

Is it the experience that we want to promote with documentation?

I feel that example should focus on one topic only and not try to cover everything.

Thoughts?

Comment: I totally agree this is very long winded and I couldn't get the past the what is an array block. Seems like the docs are for people who know what array are and just don't know how to use them in java.

Comment: Oh my... Laurel, your flag from the question is gone... Prepare for madness...

Comment: @ppeterka You have to add a comment to my post to ping me, you know `;)`. Unfortunately, I can't add the flag back while I am still editing. Of course, there is a new improvement flag, but it's not as good as mine.

Comment: @Laurel sorry - I thought the question was yours too...

Answer (score 29):

### Update:

It's been a [long and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329787) task, but I think [my draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/drafts/67066) is almost ready to publish for review. I split up the one big 600+ scored example into smaller pieces, and I also moved some Examples to their own place.
 The new array subtopics will need to be linked to the main topic, too.

The fact is the size is causing real problems, since it makes it almost impossible to edit. We need to prevent topics from swelling to this size before the browser is unable to handle it.

---

I think it should be broken up into different sections. If this answer gets enough votes, I will see about proposing the change. I'm planning on leaving the intro section intact with all its votes, and moving the other sections to their own Examples.

Look at the headers:

- Intro
- Creating and initializing primitive type arrays
- Creating and initializing multi-dimensional arrays
- Multidimensional Array representation in Java
- Creating and initializing reference type arrays
- Creating and initializing generic type arrays
- Filling an array after initialization
- Separate declaration and initialization of arrays
- Arrays may not be re-initialized with array initializer shortcut syntax
- Array initialization syntax when not in a declaration

---

In fact, that's probably too much for a single topic, given that [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) says:

> #### Keep example counts manageable
>
> The typical topic has between one and six examples, and the typical example has a paragraph of explanation and some code. As topics grow, consider splitting them and moving examples to new topics.

This is another problem, but I'm not going to worry about that yet.

Comment: Yeah, that example should probably be a whole topic for itself. "Creating and initializing arrays" topic. And be adequately be split up in tiny examples. And then use appropriate separate topics for the other examples (array manipulation, array access, iteration)

Comment: Looks to me that the titles translate in the current system to different examples. This way all the creating examples are relevant and the intro obviously isn't

Comment: @raam86 Yes, obviously. I'm just not sure how to go about proposing this change. All of the newly created examples would have 0 score...

Comment: I am not sure about that, people may scroll to the other examples and over time the most helpful parts of this monster will float to the top.

Comment: @raam86 I've edited my answer. I'm not comfortable doing anything without a consensus, so I will wait to see how voting pans out.

Comment: This needs to happen in a bunch of places, but this is probably the worst offender. [Here's an example of a topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions#t=201608022034592351306) created from [a bloated example in another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions?asOf=2016080213353338) - this is gonna be necessary if we hope to keep these things useful.

Comment: @Laurel I think your proposal is good, but I don't think you should be the one to do it.  This is something I think a moderator should handle, or at least a Java gold tag badge holder......

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm not sure if it's possible for anyone to handle this issue.  I began [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays?draftId=64377), and now my draft freezes up the tab. >:( I'm super annoyed at this right now.

Comment: @Laurel That's the universe telling you to take a break :)   but seriously, with the new rules in place, just let a gold tag badge holder take care of it, as they can edit without having to be reviewed, and their edit will hold more weight (the community will be more likely to just accept it instead of throwing a fit).

Comment: @DanielNugent No, it's not just me. This is a [known issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329787). It will be hard to fix this as a result.

Comment: @Laurel - in the short term, you could copy the current markdown to a text editor and edit it there.  Then just paste the whole lot over the top.  (Yea, it may hard to get the formatting right, but IMO that can be handled by other people with lesser skills at a later date.)

Comment: @StephenC Most of the work I was doing involved copying and pasting from example to example, so I'm not sure how much it would have helped. Ironically enough, not giving up and letting the thing work in the background allowed it to load some. I have begun to try to find new homes for some of the Examples, since it's still hard to manage. I may resort to prematurely submitting the edit (I haven't removed the content from the highly voted answer, so it is currently duplicated a little) in the hope that I can get some of the examples out of there.

Answer (score 5):

The Documentation powers-that-be have left the definition of Topic & Example intentionally nebulous -- probably so that Documentation will evolve naturally.

At the current moment in Documentation evolution, longer/multipart examples are being culled while short examples remain.

So, currently, it appears that Examples are intended to be "Cut & Paste Code" more than "Narrative tutorials" with demos on usage.

I do hope Documentation evolves to embrace long-form Examples, but for now, in my experience:

> Documentation === A collection of short code snippets (Examples)
>   related to a common Topic.

Comment: Long examples are fine and appreciated … _if_ they actually are about a specific single individual functionality. The concrete example in question is actually covering multiple examples [just look at the headers, like @Laurel outlined in his answer]. — Arrays in general is just too a too large scope for a single topic.

Comment: @bwoebi. Good to know that long-form examples are ok. :-) And agreed, the general Topic of "Arrays" is too large for a single Topic. Are you hearing any buzz about how related Topics might be organized into categories to make it easier for searchers to drill-down? So categories would be an organizational level between Tag & Topic.

Comment: "*At the current moment in Documentation evolution, longer/multipart examples are being culled while short examples remain.*" They are? Where?

Comment: @NicolBolas [An example that happend to me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330132/why-was-my-topicexamples-deleted-without-explanation)

Answer (score 4):

That *"example"* is outrageous. That is why I put *"Basic cases"* and *"Arrays, Collections, Streams"* blocks (which I mainly copied from the initial edit...), and a **TL;DR** in front of the problem. I think this covers at least 80% of the cases one would visit that example for.

The proper example-like parts of the rest should be broken off and into smaller pieces, to live as separate examples - and what remains should be discarded. Stuff like the memory layout of arrays is **not** an example.

**I feel that Documentation in general should not have TL;DR stuff.** We're not trying to write *another* book. In my book (pun int.) the whole point of Documentation is exactly that it should have the same effective content as books (guides, official docs, etc.) without the TL;DR parts to speed up getting the relevant information, and thus being far more efficient.

**I think Documentation is not there to teach people the basics.** I see it as existing for people who already code, are clear with the basics and general concepts, and proficient with at least one programming language. In my opinion, it should probably be more like a thesaurus. I don't think there should be a sentence containing *Each item in an array is called an element* in any topic. By just leaving out the fluff Documentation would be a better place.

Comment: I kinda wonder why it is so much upvoted though.

Comment: @Gudradain I think because everyone knows what arrays are, and the example has a lot of info: everyone seeing it first thinks of it s a magnificent thing, so they click the upvote (also, it is free). Also, I see highly upvoted things to attract even more votes.

Comment: In a sense, what you & I think the purpose of the documentation is / will be is not relevant.  What really matters is what the Readers think it should be.  If they want / need material on the basics, they will ask for it, and upvote it if it (sort of) meets their needs.  IMO, we need >>both kinds<< and a good way to guide people to the level of documentation that they need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion.  Maybe there should be a (soft?) limit on the size of an example.  Edits that make an example longer than (say) 100 lines or an equivalent number of words of rendered text could be banned outright, or could require a much larger number of approval votes.

From my observation, these bloated articles arise because of lots of people all adding their own little bit ... without considering the current size and scope of the example.

Comment: They might have put this in place already if they anticipated these problems in advance. Which may also be the reason performance is so poor with bloated examples.